# jaxb anyelement namespace any instead of other

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a java jaxb annotated class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement()
public class xmlDoc<T> {
@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax=false)
   protected T content;
   public T getContent() {
      return this.content;
   }
   public void setContent(T t) {
        this.content = t;
   }
}
```

When I generate the xml schema using jaxb, I get the following output

```
<xs:complexType mixed="true" name="xmlDoc">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Is there any annotation parameter in jaxb using which I can control the namespace of the any element type. I need ##any instead of ##other.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parameter to control the output of the details. But when the wsdl is generated if I modify the parameter of the namespace to ##any it will allow to convert to the existing datatype and work as required.

Comment: Does it mean, you're changing the generated xsd file manually after each generation? This is not really the solution for the question, right? Are you also using `JAXBContext.generateSchema()` to generate the file? I need to rely on the schema generator outputting ##any. Please share what you did if you really could solve it, or just open the question again for somebody else to answer.

Comment: Ok, I had a look at the source of the reference implementation and found out that the [XmlSchemaGenerator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/schemagen/XmlSchemaGenerator.java#1215) simply writes ##other hard coded for the any element. So there's not much we can do. I'll try to write a little procedure that simply replaces the ##other with ##any so that I don't have to do this manually on each generation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, I had a look at the source of the reference implementation and found out that the [XmlSchemaGenerator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/schemagen/XmlSchemaGenerator.java#1215) simply writes **##other** hard coded for the *any* element.

So, I'm replacing now the **##other** with **##any** after the file generation with the following method:

```
  private static void fixNamespaceOfAnyElementsFor(final File xsdFile) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("your_prefix", ".tmp");
    Files.move(xsdFile.toPath(), tempFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    try (final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(xsdFile.toPath())) {
      try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(tempFile.toPath())) {
        lines.map(line -> line.replace("namespace=\"##other\"", "namespace=\"##any\""))
            .forEach(line -> {
              try {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
              } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
              }
            });
      }
    }
    Files.delete(tempFile.toPath());
  }
```

It basically moves the file to a temporary folder so that I can rewrite it on the original location replacing the attribute value. When finished the temp file is deleted.

**NOTE:** First I explored solutions with DOM and Stax but they all messed up the original formatting (pretty print) of the generator. Since I'm committing the generated XSD to git and need a consistent format on each generation, I decided to go for the simple line by line solution.